# How to prevent a UITableViewCell from moving (Swift 5)

Tags: swift, uitableview, tableview, indexpath

This is actually a two part question. First take a look at the code:

```
//canEditRowAt
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    if tableView.tag == 1000{
        return indexPath.row == 0 ? false : true
        }
    return true
}

//canMoveRowAt
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    if tableView.tag == 1000{
        return indexPath.row == 0 ? false : true
    }
    return true
}
```

So from this I would expect that it would prevent the row at index 0 from having other cells move to it, but no... as you can see:

[image]

I obviously want to prevent it, but can't seem to find any documentation to solve the issue.

The other bit I'm struggling with; if you look at the recording you can see that once I move a cell into any location, a black bar appears behind the cell. I would like to avoid that from happening as well, and have tried several things but nothing has worked.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the first question, if you look at the `tableView(_:canMoveRowAt:)` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasource/1614927-tableview) :

> This method allows the data source to specify that the reordering
> control for the specified row not be shown. By default, the reordering
> control is shown if the data source implements the
> tableView(_:moveRowAt:to:) method.

This mainly talks about the `reordering control` being shown rather than specifically saying it can never be moved. So if you look at your UI, the `reordering control` is not showing for `indexPath.row == 0`

I can suggest 2 alternatives:

**1. Reverse the move action**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                        moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath,
                        to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath)
{
    // Reverse the action for the first row
    if destinationIndexPath.row == 0
    {
        // You need the give a slight delay as the table view
        // is still completing the first move animation
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5)
        {
            tableView.beginUpdates()
            tableView.moveRow(at: destinationIndexPath,
                              to: sourceIndexPath)
            tableView.endUpdates()
        }
        
        return
    }
    
    // update the data source
}
```

[image: UITableView reorder move UITableViewCell table view cell swift iOS]

**2. User a header view**

This way you don't have to worry about specify any logic of which cells can move and which cannot as you can have the non movable data in a header view:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                        viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?
{
    if section == 0
    {
        // Customize any view
        let headerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0,
                                              y: 0,
                                              width: tableView.bounds.width,
                                              height: 100))
        headerView.backgroundColor = .red
        
        let label = UILabel(frame: headerView.bounds)
        label.text = "Header view"
        label.textColor = .white
        label.textAlignment = .center
        headerView.addSubview(label)
        
        return headerView
    }
    
    return nil
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                        heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat
{
    if section == 0
    {
        // specify any height
        return 100
    }
    
    return 0
}
```

[image: UITableView custom header UIView swift iOS]

I recommend the second option as it has the better user experience and seems to be the right way of approaching this problem.

To answer your second question, in your `cellForRowAt indexPath` or custom cell implementation, you probably set the background view of the cell or the `contentView` to black.

Try setting one of these or both:

```
cell.backgroundColor = .clear
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = .clear
```

This should not give you a black background

Comment: I went with the first method, just seemed like too much of a headache for a minor gain to go with the second option. The background color I set to clear but it goes translucent when I move rows and you can still see the border of the cell with a shadow, so weird; I decided to just set it to black instead, oh well. By the way you've answered like three of my questions in a row now, you are the man! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Implement `tableView(_:targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAt:toProposedIndexPath:)` and ensure row 0 is never returned (return row 1 when `proposedDestinationIndexPath` is row 0).